# C# - MS Test - Create a test that runs another test first

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, integration-testing, mstest

In our application, I have created a login test for our website. If this test is successful then login is successful. Now to create tests for other parts of the website, I need to perform login first.

Is there a way so that all the other tests that I will create will run the login test first? For example: is it possible to create a custom login test attribute that I can put on all other test methods, so that they will run login first? But then I also need the return value from that login test !

If not, then I will have to just write a plain C# function that performs login operation and I will need to put that function call, as the first line of every test.

Comment: Just put your login logic in a method and use the `TestInitialize` attribute to automatically run it before other tests. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: But it returns some objects that I need to use in all other tests. How will I get that ?

Comment: Test should not return something and should not depend on each other, just put whole logic in a method then call the method in both tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're writing unit tests, you are testing each method in **isolation**. Meaning, the method that you're testing must not, and cannot depend on anything else in order to run.

The reason why you have a problem now, **probably** is because you broke at least the single responsability principle (the one that states that your class should only have one single reason to be changed). I can assume this because you are stating that your OTHER methods in a class depend on login being successful. Here's how to solve it:

Make an interface for your login method, something like:

```
public interface ILoginManager{
   void Authenticate(string username, string password);

   void IsAuthenticated{ get;}
}
```

Next, using the **Dependency Inversion Principle**, add this interface to your class with methods in it:

```
public class MyWorkerClass
{
  private readonly ILoginManager _loginManager;
  public MyWorkerClass(ILoginManager loginManager){
    _loginManager = loginManager;
  }


  public bool LogOnUser(string userName, string password){
    _loginManager.Authenticate(userName, password);

    return _loginManager.IsAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

Now, in all your tests, you can mock out the LoginManager, and set your expectations there, i.e.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeMethod_UserIsAuthenticated_InvokesSomeOtherMethod()
{
  // Arrange
  GetMockFor<ILoginManager>().SetupGet(lm => lm.Authenticated).Returns(true);

  // Act
  var result = Instance.SomeMethod();

  // Assert
  GetMockFor<ISomeOtherInterface>()
    .Verify(o => o.SomeOtherMethod(), Times.AtLeastOnce() );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What about a base class?

```
[TestClass]
public class AuthenticatedTest
{
  [TestInitialize]
  public void TestInitialize()
  {
    // login
  }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyTests : AuthenticatedTest
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void Whatever()
  {
    // already logged in.
  }
}
```

You should not write tests which rely on other tests. If you need to log in before, you have to log n before, not "run the login test". It is probably not much difference of the code, but of the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to start the web server before such tests, especially if it's a WCF service.  I tried all sorts of Cassini / IIS Express logic before I realized that it's only the local ASP.NET server that needs to be running:

```
static System.Diagnostics.Process server = null;

public static void RunSite()
{
    string shared = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared";
    string aspServer = shared + @"\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.EXE";
    string webSite = @"C:\Code\YourProject\WebSite";
    int port = 1234;
    var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(aspServer);
    startInfo.Arguments = "/port:" + port + " /path:" + webSite;
    server = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
}


[AssemblyInitialize]
public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
{
    RunSite();
    // login ...
}

[AssemblyCleanup]
public static void AssemblyCleanup()
{
    server.Kill();
}
```

**NOTE:** This might leave WebDev.WebServer40.EXE running, if you don't let a test debug session complete the Assembly Cleanup.  In that case, you can shut down the little yellow web page icon from the System Tray.